# Python--How to create a module from another module

Tags: python, build, module

Say I have a module X. In module X, I have a build method, which takes in a few arguments. Using those arguments, it creates a custom module and class from scratch into a certain directory. By scratch, I mean it creates the .py module from scratch, and it creates the module's class + its methods from scratch. Is using the write() function repeatedly the best way to achieve this, or is there a much simpler approach?

Answer (score 0):

If by "using the write() function repeatedly", you mean that you open the target .py file and use the file object's write method, then, yes, that's a standard way to compose files.